# Mongo.getDatabaseNames() occasionally throws CommandFailureException

Tags: mongodb

We have been having some problems where our mongo connection fails to allow us to get the database names from the DB.

We call the method:

```
com.mongodb.Mongo.getDatabaseNames()
```

And 1 out of 100 times, it throws the following exception:

```
Caused by: com.mongodb.CommandFailureException: { "serverUsed" : "localhost:27017" , 
        "errmsg" : "exception: can't open database in a read lock. if db was just closed, consider retrying the query. might otherwise indicate an internal error" , "code" : 15927 , "ok" : 0.0}
    at com.mongodb.CommandResult.getException(CommandResult.java:76)
    at com.mongodb.CommandResult.throwOnError(CommandResult.java:131)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo.getDatabaseNames(Mongo.java:397)
```

Looking at the mongo code, the database is the internal admin database

```
public List<String> getDatabaseNames(){

  BasicDBObject cmd = new BasicDBObject();
  cmd.put("listDatabases", 1);

>>CommandResult res = getDB(ADMIN_DATABASE_NAME).command(cmd, getOptions());
  res.throwOnError();
```

This database is not being deleted, but there are several other databases that could be deleted around this time.

Has anyone else had this problem?

Comment: I'd suggest filing a [SERVER ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER) about this...seems odd. I've found some related issues but this one looks a bit different.

Comment: For anyone interested, filed: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-15377    I'll post updates/conclusions over here.